# JDBC Driver & JDBC Connection string for Exadata

Tags: oracle, jdbc, exadata

I have developed a code which connects to Oracle DB using the JDBC connection string oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver & respective jar for the same.

However my customer moved to a different DB called 'Exadata' recently.

My question is since they are from same vendor 'Oracle' is there any change in the JDBC driver & JDBC connection string to Exadata DB.

Google didn't help much & instead confused me.

Any leads would be appreciated with a URL to the source as well if possible. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Exadata is a "regular" Oracle database running on specialized hardware.

There is nothing you need to change in your application.

Answer (score 0):

If they redefine the database service name in tnsnames.ora, they could reuse the code without changing the URL/connect-string.